# Why do my photos get much smaller when sending .cr2 files from ufraw to gimp?

Tags: raw, gimp, ufraw

I am using ufraw to open .cr2 raw files in gimp, but I'm experiencing a strange issue.
The .cr2 files are some 7Mb large. A typical dimension could be, for instance, 2374x1591, as reported by my camera and by ufraw itself.

While I am in ufraw everything is fine but when from ufraw I send it to gimp, it's like if the size of each side got "divided by 100": the resulting image is 24x15 and the size of the file is correspondingly only few kb.

Note that I'm shooting raw + jpg: gimp correctly opens the jpg without playing strange tricks with the size.

I have searched the web but maybe I am using the wrong keyword, since I was unable to find a solution. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For me ufraw and gimp work w/o a problem, so it most certainly a problem with your setup or your actions in the import of the RAW to gimp.

Comment: @ysap: surely I have inadvertently changed something, it's only that I cannot find what is that :) as for the actions, even this don't work: I start gimp, pick up a .cr2 file, ufraw starts and the size is correct, then I click "ok" and get back to gimp.

Comment: @ysap: in addition, I don't remember to have changed anything. I was not playing with settings...

Comment: Since my setup works just well, I don't have very smart ideas here, but: 1. Does the standalone ufraw works well (saves jpeg the right size)? 2. You can try reinstalling the software to make sure you have resetted everything.

Comment: @ysap: thanks for the suggestions, actually it was NOT saving jpg the right size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the setting which was giving me this strange behaviour. I had set it without even noticing.

It was under the `crop and rotate` tab, `scaling factor` (in italian `fattore di ridimensionamento)`. 
In my case it was set to 100, I put it back to 1 and the problem was solved. Notice that this scaling is not applied to the image while in ufraw, but only at the moment of saving/sending to gimp.

I couldn't admit defeat and reinstall without understanding, I knew that it had to be a wrong setting on my part, I went through each tab and I finally found the error :-)